# Integer equation with arbitrary number of unknowns

Tags: python, equation

I want to find all integers (x_1,x_2,x_3...,x_n) between -S and S such that x_1+...x_n =0

Below a solution for n=9 and S=1

```
solutions=[[i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q]  
                                    for q in range(-1,2) 
                                    for p in range(-1,2) 
                                    for o in range(-1,2) 
                                    for n in range(-1,2) 
                                    for m in range(-1,2) 
                                    for l in range(-1,2) 
                                    for k in range(-1,2) 
                                    for j in range(-1,2) 
                                    for i in range(-1,2) 
                                    if i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p+q== 0 ]
```

How do I do this for arbitrary n and S ?
How do I define an arbitrary number of unknowns (I know this can be done with sympy for example) put a constraint on them (don't know how to do this in python) and solve the equation above.

I can do this easily with mathematica, but not with python...

Comment: You want to solve a optimization problem with lagrange multipliers 
 https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2018/11/03/Constrained-optimization-with-Lagrange-multipliers-and-autograd/

Answer (score 2):

From an algorithmic point of view, for learning purpose, you can probably go with recursion.

From a performance and mathematical point of view, you will definitely want to go with matrice. One matrix for describing the equation system and one matrix for describing the expected result. Then you solve the system using linear algebra. Python `np` addresses, among others, this purpose with the `solve` function.

EDIT:

An other possibility comes to my mind but I doubt it is the most efficient way of achieving your goal. You can build a set of lists which express all the possible combination for `n` and `S`, and then test them and keep the ones which satisfy the initial equation. Python `itertool` can handle such generations.

Comment: Do you mean,  numpy.linalg.solve ? I am new to python ! if so, you're making it seem like it's an easy linear algebra problem, whereas the x_i should be integers between S and -S, am I missing something ?

Comment: @yfs I was thinking of this method indeed. What do you mean with "you're making it seem like it's an easy linear algebra problem"? Is it not? This should produce at least one set of solution (all 0 for instance) which satisfies the constrain.